# Android Studio Start Activity from Modul

Tags: java, android

I have created an *.aar File from a Android Studio project. This file I have successfully imported to an another Android Studio project file. Now I want start the activity from the included libraries. But i am hanging and I try hour to hour...

In wich file I have to include the statement like this?

```
 public void button_to_start_the_activity(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Should I implement this in the modul java file or in the application java file?
(Please check this out, I have not found a activity java file in my module :-/ glglgl)
Steps bevor, i have created a new activity in my main-project and i was able to start the activity without trouble.

Okay... Next question:

In the Main Manifest,...what to hell I shout declare in android:name"....?...." like this:

```
<activity
        android:name="....??????...."
        android:label="DLC"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
```

Maybe, or for sure, simple question... But i try to learn a little bit AS since a week... For your understanding, i will try to explain my project with simple words....:

Try to merge two app projects in one app!

I have created a app, then i have created an another app. Now i want to merge. Simple startpage (allready exist) with the function to call the both activitys... :-/

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Finaly the question was how to start an activity from a modul in the main app. 

I have found my solutions - see answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution to start a modul activity in the main app (For poeple with less experience like me)

1. Create in Android Studio a modul from the existing app
2. Open Main-Project an insert the new modul (File-->New-->Import Modul)
3. Right click on project folder. Search App (left side), then dependencies (right side) --> Add new from modul --> Add your modul
4. Check your build.cradle (Main-App) for **compile project(':yourmodul')**
5. Add this in your activity (from the Main-App)

   ```
    public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public void gotocalc(View view)
    {
    Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, YourModulClass.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
   ```
6. **gotocalc** is for start with a button **android:onClick="gotocalc"** set in your layout.xml in the Main App.
7. Clean, Rebuild